# Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly 'AutoMapper': 3.2.1.0

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure .net backend working just fine locally. But when I deploy to Azure, I get this msg when I use the azure test page to test the deployed service.

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly 'AutoMapper': 3.2.1.0. Please change your project to use version '3.2.0.0' which is the one currently supported by the hosting environment.'

So, my first thought was to downgrade to AutoMapper 3.2.0, but then I get into difficulty with my existing mappings that worked just fine with AutoMapper 3.2.1.

My question is why does Azure Region 'East Asia'(where my azure mobile service is deployed) have this issue ?

Do other regions suffer from this ?

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had local copies of AutoMapper binaries in my bin folder which got deployed to Azure. So, removed them and conflict was resolved.